# Failed to build project using newly compiled QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, mingw-w64

I used to build the `QtCreator` from source as a 64 bit application for my machine to do development tasks. Recently, I restored the OS and attempted to re-build the QtCreator from source but faced a weird problem. The fresh building process for the Qt library and the QtCreator completed nicely, but when I try to build a previously working project, the tool complains the following message:

```
09:39:55: Running steps for project HKPopSim...
09:39:55: Starting: "C:\QtSuite\qt-4.8-gcc-4.8\bin\qmake.exe" C:\workspace\HKPopSim\GUI\HKPopSim.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
09:39:55: The process "C:\QtSuite\qt-4.8-gcc-4.8\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
09:39:55: Starting: "make" qtcreator_ctrlc_stub: Command line failed: make
09:39:55: The process "make" crashed.
Error while building/deploying project HKPopSim (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
09:39:55: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

To start the Qtcreator, (as not to pollute the PATH env. variable), I wrote the following batch script.

```
@SETLOCAL
@SET QTCBIN=C:\QtSuite\QtCreator-2.7.1-gcc-4.8\bin
@SET QTDIR=C:\QtSuite\qt-4.8-gcc-4.8
@SET "OPATH=%PATH%"
@SET "PATH=C:\MinGW\rubenvb-4.8.0-64\bin"
@SET "PATH=%PATH%;%QTCBIN%"
@SET "PATH=%PATH%;%QTDIR%\bin"
@SET "PATH=%PATH%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32;
@START %QTCBIN%\qtcreator.exe
@ENDLOCAL
```

I don't know how come the QtCreator claims that it needs 'make.exe' for building process. I do have a 'make.exe' at C:\GNUWin32\bin, but as shown in the script, it should never be detected by the Creator.

**What have been verified:**

1. I once verified that with similar configuration on another machine, the tool call 'mingw32-make.exe' for building process.
2. The 'Compilers' setting in the QtCreator correctly (auto-)detected the only gcc compilers in the path (C:\MinGW\rubenvb-4.8.0-64\bin)
3. The 'Qt Version' setting in the QtCreator correctly (manually) detected the only qmake in the path (C:\QtSuite\qt-4.8-gcc-4.8\bin)

Please suggest anything I missed. Thanks

Platform

- Win 7 x64
- MinGW x64 (rubenvb-4.8.0)
- Qt library (4.8.5, not the latest src)
- Qt creator (2.7.1)